# Cloud Pub/Sub is available for a specific region. What does this mean? Please confirm

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

Does the release notes statement that Cloud pub/sub is available now in a specific region mean that the data movement (pushing into the topic, subscribing to a topic, storing message) happens within that region only? 
GDPR requirement (Data residency) that data shall not move from the geography where the data originated from.
Please confirm.

Answer (score 4):

Google Cloud Pub/Sub is a global service, available from everywhere. It is not possible to choose where you want your Pub/Sub service to be, but it will be in the closest region to your project location. The fact that is available in a new region means that now that region has the necessary infrastructure to host a Pub/Sub service.

Here you can see the [location of Google Cloud products](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/), and also the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/release-notes) on Pub/Sub

**[EDIT]**

Despite this, there are some ways to help you ensure compliance:

- As mentioned above, Pub/Sub takes the best effort to keep your data in the closest location to you the source of publication, and once it is stored, that data will not moved without your explicit action.
- Pub/Sub provides monitoring on data storage location, thus you can track any potential violations and take action by discarding the backlog using Pub/Sub's seek's functionality or ensuring that it is quickly processed.
- Risk can be limited by [reducing message retention duration](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery).

Comment: Thanks Pablo for the reply. How can I ensure the data residency in cloud pub/sub. Could not come across anything concrete to convince EU customers.  Its all wise guess that message store/replication, movement happens within the region of my project.

Comment: As for Pub/Sub, you cannot ensure it. You publisher should be using the resources closer to you project's location if they are available. Here you can check the [SLA for Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/sla).
Also, here you can have an [overview of Pub/Sub architecture](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture) for further information.

Comment: The first point is not actually fully correct. Data is direct to the closest location allowed and internally in background will be replicated across data centers (multiple regions or not, depends on you). Once N/2 persistence is completed, the message is marked as persisted (M number of clusters).

Answer (score 1):

Pub/Sub now supports controlling where your message data is stored.  Specifically, a topic now has a configurable message storage policy which is a list of GCP regions where Pub/Sub is allowed to store message data on disk.  When a message is published to a region not in this list, the request is forwarded to the nearest allowed region for processing. The policy can be configured on a topic or as an organizational policy for a project, project folder or an entire organization.  When an organization policy is configured, individual topic policy can be changed only in ways that do not violate the organization policy.  See: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/resource-location-restriction.