# Cloud Pub/Sub - Charges Internet data delivery from South America to North America

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I set up some Google cloud pub/sub topics and after some time noticed that I was being charged with 'Internet data delivery from South America to North America'.

See image: [GCP Billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHGcF.png)

So I google it and found that Pubsub is a global service and uses the nearest available region in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54995901/cloud-pub-sub-is-available-for-a-specific-region-what-does-this-mean-please-co).

Then I also changed all topics' storage policy to use only the southamerica-east1 region. Which is the region of my project and consumers, but I continued getting charged. [Storage Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riGZS.png)

So my questions are:

1. Why I'm getting charged?
2. And how can I avoid it?

Comment: Do you have subscribers in North America? If so, you are probably being charged to send the data to them. It is probably worth double checking that your subscribers are in fact running in and connected to Pub/Sub in southamerica-east1.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I believe all my subscribers are in south america and therefore accessing from southamerica-east1. Actually, it's just my works team that access it.

Do you u know if I can monitor which region subscribers are pulling from?